# sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unterminated `s' command

Tags: sed

I get his error when using **sed**:

```
sed 's/H/q' myout00
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unterminated `s' command

cat myout00:
Fname   Lname   Net Algo    OS  NSec    Sof
Sadegh  SamanI  15  20  14  19  15
Arash   Jami    12  20  20  18  12
Hamed   Sadeghi 13  19  16  17  13
NIma    Ehsani  20  20  17  18  20
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? It is really unterminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace `H` with `q` run it this way:

```
sed 's/H/q/' myout00
```

You didn't terminate the substitution command.